# Elasticsearch sorting by _doc with pagination using search_after does not maintain order

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, pagination, elasticsearch-5

I need to make a paginated search call to ES. I am using `_doc` as a sort key and `search_after` for getting next page, since I don't care about ordering as long as it is consistent every time I make a search. However, what I found out is that returned objects are sorted in different order on every search request. In case of pagination this actually causes problems, because when making a call to get next page I often see same documents as I saw on a previous page.

Am I misunderstanding how `_doc` should be used? What are my other alternatives if I want consistent ordering.

I am using `ES 5.5`

Comment: I am voting to close this question as off-topic because there is not enough information to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current documentation recommends using a field with one unique value per document to be used as the tiebreaker, this should be a duplicate of the `_id` field in another field that has doc values enabled.

See the search_after documentation here, specifically the first note:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-after.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use _uid for sorting but using _uid for sorting is an expensive operation in terms of memory usage. Please check this https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/11925